# SSIS Merge Join on two different DB in different sql servers won't join all rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis, inner-join

I have two databases residing in two different SQL servers (Server A and Server B) and I am trying to run a MERGE join in SSIS on a common column called "Name". I got the two tables sorted by "Name" and I did set the SortKey as 1 for "Name" column in both the Source OLE DB Output properties. I then selected the columns from both the tables to display and used INNER join and selected a destination empty table (with both column names from the two source servers) in Server C as Destination OLE DB Server. Everything looks good and package executes successfully without any errors and warnings.

But, out of 542 rows, only 35 rows match and it should match 405. When I specify LEFT JOIN in Merge Join transformation, I get 542 rows with 507 rows having NULL values from Server B (which again means it found a match only for 35 rows and not all 405).

Have tried using RTRIM on Name column from both the sources without any success.
Have tried using UPPER case on Name column from both the sources without any success as well :(

I don't get this issue when I do JOINS on same 2 databases in powershell using Invoke-SqlCommand, but when I do SSIS way, it only JOINS on 35 rows.

Can someone suggest what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Found out the issue. The two source tables were not sorted, so I had to write a SQL statement to ORDER BY Name on both sources and it worked perfectly. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Cool! I thought SSIS doesn't let you use Merge Join unless you use a sort operator!

Comment: @FLICKER You do select sort key in Source table but if your table is not sorted or if you use SQL statement for input, I had to add "ORDER BY <column_name>" even though I had specified the sort key.